# Visual Basic Webbrowser control does not show all elements of a page

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control

Using VS 2010 -- and later VS Community 2015 -- I've been trying to make a simple Windows client app that will cycle through a list of URLs and display them in the web browser control. Specifically, it's a list of my favorite online comic strips. However, whether it's in the VS 2010 environment or the VS Community 2015 environment, the web browser control does not display all of the elements on the page. Nor will they show if I run the executable outside the development environment.

For example, [at this URL](http://www.zitscomics.com), which is the Zits comic website, most of the page shows, but not the comic strip itself. At another, it shows the strip but everything on the page beneath the strip is blank. Odd, though, is that the elements appear to be there, just not visible. Running the mouse over an anchor element, for example, changes the cursor to a hand, and clicking the invisible link works.

I've looked at the source code for the pages, the code shows the elements to be there. I can't see anything in the source that shows why it wouldn't be showing up.

As I said, it does the same thing for VS 2010 and VS 2015.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It's a crappy way of having to do it, but it turns out the web browser defaults to IE7 mode, and as far as I can find, the only way to correct it is to add a registry key to set the emulation to IE11.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx

Seems like the web browser control, especially in VS 2015, would be a little more flexible than that. But it is what it is, and since this is for my own personal use, I don't have to worry about changing any registry keys in another user's machine.